# React trigger resize but don't actually resize the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to trigger a resize without actually resizing the screen as it fixes my slider.

```
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

The code above does not work, does anybody have any other ways of triggering a resize in react?

Had to use jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).resize();
```

Comment: Can't you call the `.onresize` instead?

Comment: jQuery(window).resize(); - this worked Chris!

Comment: Great, but I don't think you need to use jQuery. Try `window.onresize();` instead. Also, please don't answer questions inside the question. If you're positive this isn't a duplicate of an existing question, post your answer as actual answer. (also note that this seems to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), we should rather be fixing the slider)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you take the issue in the wrong way.

You should never rely on resize during initial view.

So your slider code have an issue on sizing which is typical when dealing with images (read the width before the image is loaded).

But if you still want to try that way

It may be depends on where do you dispatch this event ? If you dispatch it before your Slider is renderered it will not work.

A solution could be to use React.useEffect:

```
function MySlider() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch it once mounted
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); 
  }, []);
  return <div>Your stuff</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Stuck into the same problem for OpenLayer Map as well as D3 charts.
Problem is Component didn't get mount when you dispatch that Window Resize Event. Workaround is to introduce delay while firing the event.

```
setTimeout(
()=>{window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));},
2500
);
```

It should work.

Comment: I had a similar issue using Mapbox map with GL.JS.   The above code fixed it, however the critical aspect was dispatching the event in a separate thread, rather than the delay itself.  I was able to get this to work with the timeout set to only 1 ms .