# highcharts stock chart not resizing when sidebar opens

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, resize

I show a `highstock` chart in a container. My application is wrapped with a dashboard-layout where I can toggle the sidebar on and off.

By default the sidebar is open. When I open or close the sidebar I call a `window.resize` event and trigger a resize of the chart. This works perfectly when I close the sidebar, but when I open again the `chartWidth` is larger than the `containerWidth`.

I also checked with a simple `MUI` `Box` component, that the container resized properly on opening and closing of the sidebar. Only the chart doesn't.

Here is my `onClick()` event for the opening and closing of the sidebar:

```
onClick={() =>
  {
    toggleIsOpened(!isOpened);
    var isResized = window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    console.log("isResized:",isResized);
    for (var i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
      if (Highcharts.charts[i] !== undefined) {
        Highcharts.charts[i].reflow();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to update the `chartWidth` manually but this doesn't work either.

```
Highcharts.charts[i].setSize(
  Highcharts.charts[i].containerWidth,
  false
);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Update:

I found a workaround according to this solution

> Problem is Component didn't get mount when you dispatch that Window
> Resize Event.

: [React trigger resize but don't actually resize the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644793/react-trigger-resize-but-dont-actually-resize-the-screen)

```
setTimeout(
  ()=>{window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));},
   50
);
```

But I don't like this approach as there is a artificial delay in the response. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @smaica, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You can use chart.reflow() in useEffect to reflow the chart to fit the width of the container div.

```
<HighchartsReact ref={chartRef} />

 const chart = chartRef.current?.chart;
 chart.reflow();
```

Comment: Thanks, sajjad. As you can see in my code example I already used the `reflow` method after I called the resize event. Didn't work.